# Finding vectors within Underdetermined Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the underdetermined linear system

```
x + 2y − z + 2w = 6

5x + 10y − 3z + 16w = 34

3x + 6y + 2z + 21w = 28
```

Find three vectors l, m and n in R^4
such that the solutions to the system have the form λl+µm+n
where λ, µ ∈ R are free variables.

I have reduced the matrix down to

```
1 2 0 5 8

0 0 1 3 2

0 0 0 0 0
```

and have determined that

x = 8-2y-5w

y=y

z = 2-3w

w=w

are the free variables here x and z? and where do I go from here to conclude?

Answer (score 1):

> are the free variables here x and z? and where do I go from here to conclude?

Not quite, the free variables are $y$ and $w$ here, notice that once you choose $y$ and $w$ all of $x,y,w,z$ are determined. You are very close to concluding, just one small thing left to do...

If you don't mind, to make this a little clearer, (at least to myself), I will say $y = \alpha$ and $w = \beta$ for free variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Then the solutions take the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ w \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 8 - 2\alpha - 5\beta \\ \alpha \\ 2 - 3\beta \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \alpha\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \beta\begin{pmatrix} -5 \\ 0 \\ -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: not to be nitty, but I think that the last value of the last vector should be 1 because $w$=$\beta$. Thanks for the explanation, very nice.

Comment: @Alin You're totally correct, I'll edit it now for the sake of future readers. Thanks!